# change input value based on another text field in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

New to Angular here. I need to change the value of my hidden input 'cc_card' based on the first digit of the 'cc_number' input field. Ex. If a user types 5 in cc_number the hidden inputs value will be 'MasterCard', if a user types a 4 the hidden inputs value will be 'Visa' etc...

Here is my setup:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="prefixes={visa: '4', mastercard:'5', amex:'3', discover:'6'}" style="margin-bottom:25px;">    
    <div>
        <h1>Payment details</h1>
    </div>

    <div>   
        <input name="cc_number" class="text-box" type="text" id="cc_number" value="" size="30" maxlength="30" required="required" placeholder="Credit card number" ng-model="prefixes.cards">
        <input type="hidden"  name="cc_card" id="cc_card" value="" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <div>
        <img id="visa" src="images/visa-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '4'}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img id="mastercard" src="images/master-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '5'}"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img id="amex" src="images/amex-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '3'}"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img id="discover" src="images/discover-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '6'}"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `ngKeyup` or `ngKeypress` to trigger a function on a key event.. then do some checking and set your hidden field

Comment: You need to add `ngModel` to the hidden input, and `ngChange` to `cc_number` so when the value is changed you can set a value to the hidden input from the controller

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you. This sound about right, but again I'm very new to angular, how would I set up the ngchange? would it just call a function I create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to add `ngModel` to the hidden input and change the model of that input when the value of `#cc_number` input changes.

To detect the change you add `ngChange` to `#cc_number` and pass a function that will validate the input.

In this example I'm using the actual value that is bound to the hidden input to toggle the `.greyed` class from the credit cards. Try changing the value of the input to **4**, then **5** and **6** and you'll see that the relevant credit card name get visible, according to the value of the input.

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.prefixes = {};
  $scope.ccNumberChnage = function() {
    var ccType = $scope.prefixes.cards ? $scope.prefixes.cards.charAt(0) : '';
    switch(ccType) {
      case '4': $scope.prefixes.type = 'mastercard'; break;
      case '5': $scope.prefixes.type = 'amex'; break;
      case '6': $scope.prefixes.type = 'discover'; break;
      default: $scope.prefixes.type = null; break;
    }
  };

});
```

```css
.greyed {background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="prefixes={visa: '4', mastercard:'5', amex:'3', discover:'6'}" style="margin-bottom:25px;">    
    <div>
        <h1>Payment details</h1>
    </div>

    <div>   
        <input name="cc_number" class="text-box" type="text" id="cc_number" value="" size="30" maxlength="30" required="required" placeholder="Credit card number" ng-model="prefixes.cards" ng-change="ccNumberChnage()">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="prefixes.type" name="cc_card" id="cc_card" value="" />
    </div>

 
   
    <div id="mastercard" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.type !== 'mastercard'}">mastercard</div>
    <div id="amex" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.type !== 'amex'}">discover</div>
    <div id="discover" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.type !== 'discover'}">discover</div>
</div>
```

As a sidenote - If you're actually going to process and store credit card numbers you must make sure that you're a [PCI](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/faq/) compliant hosting provider.

Comment: Ahh I see what you did here. An added note, In order to populate the hidden fields value on the change I had to use ng-value. It's working as expected thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question. I will add the answer for Angular 12.

suppose you have the following 2input fields:

```
<input type='text' value = '' name='firstName' formControlName="firstName">
<input type='text' value = '' name='companyName' formControlName="companyName">
```

Suppose you need to fill the companyName automatically with the value of firstName field, so, you will need to add a change event to the firstName input field.

```
<input type='text' value = '' name='firstName' (change)="OnInputChange()" formControlName="companyName">
```

Then, in the component.ts file use the patchValue method.
suppose the form group is called `RegisterForm`

```
OnInputChange(){
     this.RegisterForm.patchValue({
     companyName : this.RegisterForm.get('firstName')?.value;
   })
}
```

If you need to use a string functions such as split(), then you need to do the following:

```
OnInputChange(){
      let firstName = this.RegisterForm.get('firstName')?.value;
      this.RegisterForm.patchValue({
         companyName : firstName.split();
       })
    }
```

this is because the value type of  `this.RegisterForm.get('firstName')?.value` is `any` and you will get an error if you use split() method on a value of type `any`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div  ng-app="appName" ng-controller="appCtrl" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
         <div>
             <h1>Payment details</h1>
         </div>

         <div>
             <input name="cc_number" class="text-box" type="text" id="cc_number" value="" size="30" maxlength="30" required="required"
                    placeholder="Credit card number" ng-model="prefixes.cards" ng-keyup="vm.updateInput(prefixes.cards)">
             <input type="hidden"  name="cc_card" id="cc_card"  ng-model="prefixSelected"/>

         </div>

         <div>
             <div>
                 <img id="visa" src="images/visa-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '4'}" />
             </div>
             <div>
                 <img id="mastercard" src="images/master-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '5'}"  />
             </div>
             <div>
                 <img id="amex" src="images/amex-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '3'}"  />
             </div>
             <div>
                 <img id="discover" src="images/discover-card-logo.png" ng-class="{'greyed' : prefixes.cards.charAt(0) !== '6'}"  />
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <script>
         var app = angular.module('appName', []);
         app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope..updateInput = function(value){
        console.log('true3', value);
        // $scope.prefixes = {visa: '4', mastercard:'5', amex:'3', discover:'6'};
        switch (value){
            case '4':
                $scope.prefixSelected = 'visa';
                break;
            case '5':
                $scope.prefixSelected = 'mastercard';
                break;
            case '3':
                $scope.prefixSelected = 'amex';
                break;
            case '6':
                $scope.prefixSelected = 'discover';
                break;
            default:{
                $scope.prefixSelected = '';
                break;
            }
        }
    };
     });
     </script>
```